# Trigger action from view within scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am making an app where the user can switch between views using `scrollview`, it is like paging with scroll view. I instantiate 3 `viewcontrollers` and then put them side by side in the scroll view. The layout and everything are working, the only problem I have, that for some reason I cannot get any button or control to trigger any action/function in the third `Viewcontroller.`

The first one is just a placeholder, but everything in the second view works, but the third just does not trigger anything. Here is a picture so you can see the setup:

[image: storyboard]

My question is, what can I do so that the segmented control can trigger actions in the third view?

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: Here is some code if it helps!

```
var appllicationPages: [UIView] {
    get {
        let firstPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OnboardPageNames.firstPage).view!
        let secondPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OnboardPageNames.secondPage).view!
        let thirdPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OnboardPageNames.thirdPage).view!
        
        return [firstPage,secondPage,thirdPage]
    }
}

func setupScrollView(from pages: [UIView])
{
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(pages.count), height: view.frame.height)
    
    for i in 0 ..< pages.count {
        pages[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(pages[i])
    }
}
```

And then the function in VC three which is not executing (i hooked the segmented control up with Storyboard)

```
@IBAction func typeSwitched(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Hello There")
}
```

Comment: From your explanation, I got that you want to trigger an action only in the third view controller, and not in the class where scroll view is placed. Considering this, it seems like you are not correctly triggering the actions you want in the third view controller class. If you want actions to be triggered in the class where your scroll view is placed, then you will have to use some communication pattern (say delegation pattern) between your scroll view container class and third view controller in order for the actions to work fine.

Comment: If still this doesn't work, you may show the code!

Comment: @AmaisSheikh Thank you for your response, yes i want that action to only happen in the third VC. I just made an ibaction using storyboard (that would be the action), but i made it the same way for a button in the second VC, and there it functions how it should.

Comment: @ElliotCzigány - is this the actual code you are using? What you've shown is loading the **view** from each of 3 storyboard view controllers, but you're not loading any **code** from those view controllers.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way. If you want your view with proper functionality, you must look into the concept of child view controllers, instantiate a view controller the add it's view to your child view controller containing view. The rest is specified by @DonMag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers of DonMag and Amais Sheikh i managed to solve the problem!

As described in the comments, the problem was, that i only loaded the views, and not the controllers.

So i just had to add two lines of code:

```
func setupScrollView(from pages: [UIViewController])
{
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(pages.count), height: view.frame.height)
    
    for i in 0 ..< pages.count {
        pages[i].view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(pages[i].view)
        let VC = pages[i]
        
        // These lines helped me solve the problem
        self.addChild(VC)
        VC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

And i changed the array to ViewController instead of Views:

```
var appllicationPages: [UIViewController] {
    get {
        let firstPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainAppPages.firstPage)
        let secondPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainAppPages.secondPage)
        let thirdPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainAppPages.thirdPage)
        
        return [firstPage,secondPage,thirdPage]
    }
}
```